# time option doesn't work

Tags: linux, bash, time

I tried to measure execution time and format it with this command:

```
time -f "%e" ./1 1000 1
-f: command not found

real    0m0.066s
user    0m0.044s
sys 0m0.023s
```

But such command works:

```
/usr/bin/time -f "%e" ./1 1000 1
31245 212 443
0.00
```

I tried to determine where another time is located, but all showes to /usr/bin/time

```
which time
/usr/bin/time
```

or

```
whereis time
time: /usr/bin/time /usr/bin/X11/time /usr/include/time.h /usr/share/man/man7/time.7.gz /usr/share/man/man2/time.2.gz /usr/share/man/man1/time.1.gz
```

or

```
type -a time
time is a shell keyword
time is /usr/bin/time
```

How to define where another time is located?

Comment: `time is a shell keyword` is the key here. It is a shell built-in.

Comment: @EtanReisner `time` is a keyword, not a builtin!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Indeed. I'm not overly careful with that distinction though I likely should be.

Comment: You have a wonderful `time` keyword in Bash that allows timing on complex pipelines, something that the external `time` can't come even close to. Why don't you want to use it? is it because you don't like its output format? You can change it as you like. To mimic your example: `TIMEFORMAT=%2R; time ./1 1000 1`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Users of the bash shell need to use an explicit path in order to run
  the external time command and not the shell builtin variant.  On system
  where time is installed in /usr/bin, the first example would become

```
   /usr/bin/time wc /etc/hosts
```

OR

Note: some shells (e.g., bash(1)) have a built-in time command that
       provides less functionality than the command described here.  To
       access the real command, you may need to specify its pathname
       (something like /usr/bin/time).

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html

Comment: `\time` and `command time` will also avoid the built-in in favor of the external command.

Comment: Or `'time'` (with quotes) or `command time`. By the way, `time` is not a builtin; I mean it's not treated as a command; it's a keyword. The difference is subtle `:D` and that's why tricks like `\time` or `'time'` or `command time` work. And it must be a keyword and not a builtin to allow timing of pipelines and groups, etc.